# how can write this code more efficiently?

Tags: php

I have this code, how can I write this  more efficiently using a for loop?
I repeat this istructions for

```
 if ($_POST['qta1']!=0){ $ordine1="<tr><td>".$_POST['portata1']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta1']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta1']*$_POST['prezzo1']." €</td></tr>";}

if ($_POST['qta2']!=0){ $ordine2="<tr><td>".$_POST['portata2']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta2']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta2']*$_POST['prezzo2']." €</td></tr>";}

if ($_POST['qta3']!=0){ $ordine3="<tr><td>".$_POST['portata3']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta3']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta3']*$_POST['prezzo3']." €</td></tr>";}

if ($_POST['qta4']!=0){ $ordine4="<tr><td>".$_POST['portata4']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta4']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta4']*$_POST['prezzo4']." €</td></tr>";}

if ($_POST['qta5']!=0){ $ordine5="<tr><td>".$_POST['portata5']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta5']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta5']*$_POST['prezzo5']." €</td></tr>";}
```

I reiterated this instruction for a hundred items but it doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: Use a `for` loop?

Comment: no, but i want use it

Comment: how could i repeat this instruction 100 times? if ($_POST['qta1']!=0){ $ordine1="<tr><td>".$_POST['portata1']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta1']."</td><td>".$_POST['qta1']*$_POST['prezzo1']." €</td></tr>";}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through your post data and insert it into an array. Just try:

```
$number_of_inputs = 5;

$ordine = array();

for($i=1; $i<=$number_of_inputs; $i++) {
    if ($_POST['qta'.$i] != 0) {
        $ordine[$i] = "<tr><td>".$_POST['portata'.$i]."</td><td>".$_POST['qta'.$i]."</td><td>".$_POST['qta'.$i]*$_POST['prezzo'.$i]." €</td></tr>";
    }
}

print_r($ordine);
```